# Split Uppercase words in Excel and insert delimiters

Tags: vba, excel

I have this string:

```
RugbyFunny RugbyGirls RugbyBoys RugbyWomens Rugby
```

Basically, I would like to split the words by capital letters and put a delimiter like `;`.

I have found a useful VBA function that does part of the job:

```
Function splitbycaps(inputstr As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As String

    If inputstr = vbNullString Then
        splitbycaps = temp
        Exit Function
    Else
        temp = inputstr
        For i = 1 To Len(temp)
            If Mid(temp, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(temp, i, 1)) Then
                If i <> 1 Then
                    temp = Left(temp, i - 1) + " " + Right(temp, Len(temp) - i + 1)
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        splitbycaps = temp
    End If
End Function
```

How can I put a delimiter between each word? I would like to produce this outcome:

```
Rugby;Funny Rugby;Girls Rugby;Boys Rugby;Womens Rugby;
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function to this:

```
Function SplitByCaps(InputStr As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As String

    If InputStr = vbNullString Then
        SplitByCaps = temp
        Exit Function
    Else
        temp = InputStr
        Do While i < Len(temp)
            i = i + 1
            If Mid(temp, i, 1) <> LCase(Mid(temp, i, 1)) Then
                If i <> 1 Then
                    If Mid(temp, i - 1, 1) <> " " Then
                        temp = Left(temp, i - 1) & ";" & Right(temp, Len(temp) - i + 1)
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            DoEvents
        Loop
        SplitByCaps = temp
    End If
End Function
```

Edit: Changed it to a `Do` loop the `For` counted incorrectly as @Vityata pointed out.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim str As String
    str = "RugbyFunny RugbyGirls RugbyBoys RugbyWomens Rugby"

    Debug.Print SplitByCaps(str)
    'Rugby;Funny Rugby;Girls Rugby;Boys Rugby;Womens Rugby
End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks! how can incorporate it into the above code posted in my initial question? Once again, many thanks!

Comment: `str = "KRugbyFunny RugbyGirls RugbyBoys RugbyWomens Rugby K TB"` does not return what is needed.

Comment: @Vityata well since the requirement was "*split the **words** by capital letters*" and `K` or `TB` are no words, your example does not fulfill the requirements too ;)

Comment: In English `A` and `I` are words.

Comment: Then I don't see what should be wrong according to his wanted output `Rugby;Funny Rugby;Girls Rugby;Boys Rugby;Womens Rugby;` he obviously wants a `;` before every capital letter if there is not already a space before it. My code dose exactly that.

Comment: If the input is `RugbyFunny RugbyGirls RugbyBoys RugbyWomens Rugby IIII` then there is no `;` before every capital letter if there is not already a space before it. Pls, tag me when you answer.

Comment: @Vityata Eww sorry you are totally right, my bad. The `For` loop didn't count correctly because the `Len(temp)` changed after the loop started. Didn't see that at first because just took the OPs code to improve it instead of writing it from scratch. Corrected it into a `Do` loop. Still `IIII` might be a little strange example.

Comment: I have probably spent too much time in sites like codeforeces.com and topcoder.com - try this with your code, it is breaking - `"I IIIRugbyFunny RugbyGirls RugbyBoys RugbyWomens RugbyII"`

Comment: @Vityata arg :( now it does. Hopefully.

Comment: What would happen if you start with a space? `str = " I IIIRugbyFunny RugbyGirls RugbyBoys RugbyWomens RugbyII"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176138/discussion-between-p-and-vityata).

Comment: @Stefano Have a look at the updated code. As Vityata pointed out the `For` loop in the previous code counted wrong. This should give you the correct results now.

Answer (score 1):

Compare based on ASCII values

```
For i = 1 To Len(TEMP)
    If i <> 1 Then
        If Asc(Mid(TEMP, i, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(Mid(TEMP, i, 1)) <= 90 Then
            TEMP = Left(TEMP, i - 1) + ";" + Right(TEMP, Len(TEMP) - i + 1)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: In the general case the answer should work, but there are people out there who use strange alphabets and strange characters like ÜÖЪ. Read this article, it explains quite a lot - https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find all the positions of the string, where:

- The char is an UpperCase
- The char is actually a letter
- There is no space before the char

Then, these positions can be saved in a collection. This is a function, finding the next uppercase position, returning `-1`, if there is not such:

```
Public Function NextUpperCasePosition(str As String, marker As Long) As Long

    Dim i As Long

    Dim isUpper As Boolean
    Dim isLetter As Boolean
    Dim noSpaceBefore As Boolean

    If marker = 1 Then
        NextUpperCasePosition = 1
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = marker To Len(str)

        noSpaceBefore = CBool(Len(Trim(Mid(str, i - 1, 1))) > 0)
        isUpper = CBool(Mid(str, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(str, i, 1)))
        isLetter = CBool(LCase(Mid(str, i, 1)) <> UCase(Mid(str, i, 1)))

        If isUpper And isLetter And noSpaceBefore Then
            NextUpperCasePosition = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    NextUpperCasePosition = -1

End Function
```

Once you are able to find the positions and add them to a collection of positions, you can loop through the collection and split the string to an array, based on these numbers. Once the array is ready, the Join(arr, "; ") works quite ok to produce the needed string:

```
Public Sub SplitByUpperCase()

    Dim str As String
    str = "KRugbyFunny RugbyGirls RugbyBoys RugbyWomens Rugby K TB"

    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As New Collection
    Dim nextPosition As Long: nextPosition = 1

    For i = 1 To Len(str) Step 1
        If i = nextPosition Then
            nextPosition = NextUpperCasePosition(str, nextPosition)
            If nextPosition >= 1 Then result.Add (nextPosition)
            nextPosition = nextPosition + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Dim resultArr As Variant
    ReDim resultArr(result.Count - 1)
    Dim lenOfWord As Long

    For i = 1 To result.Count
        If i = result.Count Then
            lenOfWord = Len(str) - result(i) + 1
        Else
            lenOfWord = result(i + 1) - result(i)
        End If
        resultArr(i - 1) = Mid(str, result(i), lenOfWord)
    Next i

    Debug.Print Join(resultArr, "; ")

End Sub
```